# iAd Framework issue

Tags: iphone, ios5, iad

Has anyone worked with the iAd framework? Actually, I am trying to implement Location Based Advertising(LBA) in which the ads would be sent to the user based on his location. So does Apple's iAd framework supports LBA?

Comment: It sounds like you want to choose what ads are shown based on location. Apple picks each ad so you don't get to pick specific ads per geographic location or any other metric. Though you can say which types should be excluded based on audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. In fact, iAds are currently available at just a few countries, as you can check here: http://developer.apple.com/iad/

If a user from any other country than these opens up your app, no Ads will appear.

I am from Brazil and tried iAds for some time, but since my apps are mainly used by brazilians (iAds are not available here yet), I have recently switched to AdMob.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but hasn't Apple stopped using of any other frameworks other than iAd for displaying ads.I have read about it in some documents.

Comment: I don't know about that. However, my app with AdMob was recently updated by me and was aproved by Apple, so maybe this restriction was suspended.